Why does canvas.toDataURL() and canvas.toBlob() produce corrupt images on Firefox?
On Chrome and Safari, I am not having problem generating a snapshot image of a video. However, I've been for hours trying several different things on Firefox, but the image always comes corrupted, with a "random color" each time.
Example minimal code - https://jsfiddle.net/4uy8j1bf/1/
Basically, I'm loading a video file into a <video element, and then draw it on a <canvas>, and from there, generate either a data URL or blob URL.
But, while Chrome and Safari have no problem getting the canvas image, Firefox always gives corrupt images, even if I seek / change the video time (any video).
The canvas image is drawn fine. It's the generation of data/blob URL that doesn't seem to work.
Do you know why? What can I do to get this working on Firefox?
--
Firefox:

Chrome:

The example code:
var _CANVAS = document.querySelector("#video-canvas");
var _CTX = _CANVAS.getContext("2d");
var _VIDEO = document.querySelector("#main-video");

$("#file").on('change', function() {

    // Object Url as the video source
    $("#main-video").attr('src', URL.createObjectURL($("#file")[0].files[0]));

    // Load the video and show it
    _VIDEO.load();
        _VIDEO.currentTime = 0;
        _VIDEO.play();

    // Load metadata of the video to get video duration and dimensions
    _VIDEO.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        // Set canvas dimensions same as video dimensions
        _CANVAS.width = _VIDEO.videoWidth;
        _CANVAS.height = _VIDEO.videoHeight;
    });

    _VIDEO.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
        _CANVAS.style.display = 'inline';
        _CTX.drawImage(_VIDEO, 0, 0, _VIDEO.videoWidth, _VIDEO.videoHeight);
        
        // var dataUrl = _CANVAS.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
        // $('body').append('<img src="'+dataUrl+'" />');
        
        _CANVAS.toBlob(blob => {
            if (blob) {
                const dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                $('body').append('<img src="'+dataUrl+'" />')
            } else {
                console.log('Error creating blob from canvas');
            }
        }, 'image/png');
    });
});


seems to work just fine

Do you have browser extensions on? Does it work when you draw something else than a video? Can you try with videos from other sources, e.g. this fiddle.

Unable to reproduce - putting the  HTML, JS and CSS  into a code snippet ran with out problems in Firefox on both the SO site and locally using file:// protocal files saved on my PC. Please do not leave out the CSS and HTML information when posting on SO - particularly for these type of questions that don't require a fiddle.

Thank you all. Strange... I disabled all extensions, and even changed browser privacy from "Custom" to "Standard", restarted, and still doesn't work. Then I installed Firefox Nightly (which uses a different profile), and this works in there...
I tried also going through the Settings and made them consistent to the default in Nightly, but didn't resolve the problem either. @Kaiido - same issue happens with that fiddle you gave me. I see a big "blue corrupt" image. Works fine on Chrome and FF Nightly

Ok - looks like it was because privacy.resistFingerprinting was set to true, in "about:config" !

This happens if privacy.resistFingerprinting is set to true, in about:config.
Disabling this config, setting it to false (the default), resolves this problem.
